# FPC код 201, массивов не использую

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Заранее извиняюсь за детский, школьный и глупый вопрос. Написал данный ниже код для решения задачи из задачника Абрамова №80. По решению могу сказать, что можно спокойно решить задачу через экспоненты, но мне нужно именно решение в таком стиле. Запустил данный код. Пример с единицей запустился нормально, ответ показал правильный. С двойкой и дальше уже началась проблема: выдает ошибку 201. При этом я не использую в решении массивов. Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь поможет мне в этом.

```
{Function of factorial}
function fact(x: integer): extended;
var
    i: integer;
begin
    fact:=1;
    for i:=2 to x do
            fact:=fact*i;
end;
var
    z: -1..1;
    x,i: integer;
    sum: extended;
begin
    clrscr;
    writeln('Abramov 80');
    write('X: ');
    readln(x);
    sum:=x;
    z:=1;
    for i:=2 to 13 do
    begin
        if (i mod 2) <> 0 then
        begin
                z:=z*(-1);
                sum:=sum+z*(x/fact(i));
        end;
        x:=x*x;
    end;
    writeln(sum:0:4);
    readkey;
end.
```

Comment: Паскаль не помню, но почему у вас функция fact() ни чего не возвращает?

Comment: Как не возвращает? В паскале вместо return используется присвоение возвращаемого значения названию функции. Там напечатано:  fact:=fact*i;

Comment: @R.Abdulaev: а нормально, что оно многократно присваивается?

Comment: тут проблема в строке `fact:=fact*i;` тут с левой стороны это возврашение функции а с правой стороны обрашение не правильное

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev там все нормально, так тоже можно. Справа не вызов функции, а ее текущий результат.

Comment: Что такое "Ошибка 201"? Описание у нее есть?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci справа он не может использовать название функции как переменное. Хотя бы до pascal 7.1 было так. и в этом коде программа думаю не доходит до этой строки

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev в заголовке написано FPC, но, возможно, там тоже все так как вы говорите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

исправьте функцию факториала

```
function fact(x: integer): extended;
var
      f, i: integer;
begin
  if (x<2) then fact:=1;
  f:=1;
  for i:=2 to x do
    f:=f*i;
  fact:=f;
end;
```

или проше с рекурсией

```
function fact(x: integer): extended;
var
      f, i: integer;
begin
  if (x<2) then fact:=1;
  fact:=x*fact(x-1);
end;
```

- сливки

1) вместо

```
z:=z*(-1);
```

можно

```
z:=-z;
```

2) вместо

```
for i:=2 to 13 do
    begin
        if (i mod 2) <> 0 then
```

можно

```
for h:=1 to 6 do
    begin
        i:=h*2+1;
```

Comment: Не работает. Код ошибки 201. Напомню, компилятор free pascal.

Comment: Только что проверил исходный код на свежескачанном FPC под Win32. Вычисления производятся, никаких ошибок не выводится.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Ошибка сегментации. Запускаю на FPC for linux, дистрибутив debian. Изменил код. Предлагаю взглянуть: [ссылка](http://puu.sh/jW4GV/aee5b35278.png) (справа продолжение левого кода). Как я получил ошибку: 1) [ссылка](http://puu.sh/jW4Jb/4ca5c9e080.png) 2) [ссылка](http://puu.sh/jW4Le/58723f2a50.png)